# Problems with $broadcast in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service, `AuthenticationService` and a controller `HeaderCtrl`. When the user is logged on, my server sends me his first and last name, which I change in my service and broadcast it. Then I want to use it in my controller. However, `$on` is apparently never called.

Service code:

```
service.setName = function(first_name, last_name){
    service.firstName = first_name;
    service.lastName = last_name;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('nameChanged');
    console.log('wtf');
};
```

Controller code:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', function ($scope, $location, AuthenticationService) {

        $scope.$on('nameChanged', function(){
            console.log('ftw');
            $scope.firstName = AuthenticationService.firstName;
            $scope.lastName = AuthenticationService.lastName;
        });
    }]);
```

I can see *wtf* in console, and cannot see *ftw*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check if the controller is already instantiated when you are broadcasting (add a console.log on the first line of the controller).

Otherwise the controller misses the broadcast because it turns on it's listener after the broadcast is over.

Comment: yeah. according to console, I broadcast and then the controller is instantiated. but how can I controll the order of loading?

Comment: nevermind, I just added the initialization from inside `$on` to the beginning of the controller's body

Comment: Take out the $broadcast and $on. Instead, have the service return a promise - have the controller use that to set the firstName and lastName.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inject the service into controller and bind to the data in service directly. With that you elminate need for manual synchronziation using events. Actualy you are doing it already but only after you trigger the event.

If you store those properties on object like `AuthenticationService.user.firstName` then you can bind it to controller in the begining like: `$scope.user = AuthenticationService.user` and you will get automaticaly synchronzied data for free.

Comment: Because I have another controller that manages login form, and he sends info to `AuthenticationService`, and that's ok. But then, I need to have person's name in the header of each page, so there is that

Comment: Oh, I got your question. Well, because user can log out and another user can log in, and that data should change in controller also, but in your version it would not

Comment: It would if you use `angular.copy()` which preserves original reference, it wouldn't work if you break reference by reassigning `user` in service like this: `this.user = newUserInfo;`

Comment: So you should use `angular.copy(newUserInfo, this.user)` and this will preserve reference and automaticly update your view without need for events. I wrote a blog post about it check https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/model-pattern-for-angular-js-67494389d6f